# session_start seems to be very slow (but only sometimes)

Tags: php, apache, session, debian, fastcgi

For some odd reason, just today our server decided to be very slow during the starting of sessions. For every session_start, the server either times out after 30 seconds, or it'll take about 20 seconds for it to start the session. This is very weird, seeing as it hasn't done this for a very long time (the last time our server did this was about 7 months ago). I've tried to change the session to run through a database instead, and that works fine, however, as our current website is built, it'd take days to go on every page and change the loading of sessions to include a new session handler. Therefore my question remains:

Why is it so slow, and why only sometimes?

We run on a dedicated hetzner server with 24GB's of ram, and a CPU fast enough to just run a simple webserver (a Xeon, I believe, but I'm not sure). We run debian on the server with an apache+fastcgi+php5 setup.

The server doesn't report much load, neither through server-status as well as the `top` command. `Vnstat` reports no problem whatsoever with our network link (again, that wouldn't result in a slow local session handling). `IOtop` reports no problem with processes taking over the entire harddrive. Writing to the tmp folder where the session files are located works fast if done through vim.

Again, to make this clear, my main concern here isn't whether or not we should switch to a DB or a memory-cached version of the sessions, it's simply to ask why this happens, because everything I take a look at seems to be working fine, except for the PHP itself.

**EDIT**:
The maximum file in our PHP tmp directory is 2.9 MB, so nothing that should make an impact, I believe.

**UPDATE**: I did never figure out what was wrong and/or how to fix it, but the problem disappeared after we switched over to memcached/db sessions.

Comment: Have a look in your `tmp` directory. PHP stores it's sessions there. See if anything is amiss.

Comment: Something wrong with the disk or the filesystem perhaps?

Comment: "it'd take days to go on every page and change the loading of sessions to include a new session handler" If that's the case you seriously should consider fixing that fact first

Comment: RepWhoringPeeHaa @ As I mentioned, I'd definitely do that. I've been moved into the system with my job, so unfortunately I haven't created the session management that the application has had. It's not been something that we've been needed to fix either, since, as mentioned, there's been no problem for over 7 months.

Comment: Were there any changes done recently that you think are forcing this behavior ? Can you look at the last part of the log files from yesterday and see if something indicating trouble was logged ?

Comment: @happybuddha As I've updated in the OP, we ended up switching over to memory cached sessions instead after it happened yet again. No changes were made beforehand, and the problem randomly (at least it seems random) disappears again. (Note, this question is 11 months old).

Comment: @h2ooooooo : >  (Note, this question is 11 months old). SMH !

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/13772074/168034

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried `session_write_close();` ?
This will disable write-ability in session variables but you can still read data from them. And later when you need to write a session variable, reopen it.

I have also suffered from this problem but this thing worked like a charm. This is what i do:

```
session_start(); //starts the session
$_SESSION['user']="Me";
session_write_close();   // close write capability
echo $_SESSION['user']; // you can still access it
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem: suddenly the server took 30 seconds to execute a request. I noticed it was because of **session_start()**. The first request was fast, but each next request took some **30 sec** to be executed. 
I found that the session file in c:\wamp\tmp was locked by the first request for some 30 sec. During this time the second request was waiting for the file to be unlocked. 
I found out it had something to do with **rewrite_mod** and **.htaccess**. I disabled rewrite_mod and commented out every line in .htaccess and it works again like a charm. I don't know why this happend because I don't remember change any settings or conf on wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Each session is stored by apache as a text file.

When session start is use to resume an existing session (via cookie identifier for example) maybe a big session file (a Session with a lot of content inside) can be slow to be started?

If this is the case probably you application is putting to much data into sessions.

Comment: The biggest file in our tmp folder is 2.9MB, so nothing that _should_ make an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have correct memcache settings e.g. in `/etc/php.d/memcached.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Sessions also may start slow if you put many data in it. For example 50MB of data in session in docker image may result in 3 seconds of session start time.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but I've just fixed this issue on my server. All I did was turn on the bypass cache for the domains in the cache manager in the cpanel.

My sessions were taking ages to start and close now they are instant.