# session_start() takes long time and makes pages pending

Tags: php, ajax, session

I've used the session_start() func in the ajax files.
First File:

```
<?php
// First File
if(session_id() == '')
    session_start();
sleep(10);
```

And Second File: (run after 10 seconds, I don't know Why!)

```
<?php
// Second File
if(session_id() == '')
    session_start();
echo 'Second File'; // print after 10 seconds...
```

When I'm run two Ajax files at the same time, the second file will wait(pending) until the first file to be completed.
What is the reason? The problem has resolved when i removed session_start().
How to solve this problem?

Comment: because you have `sleep(10)`, take it out.... `sleep` will  delay execution

Comment: why are you give sleep(10) in php file you can try in Jquery

Comment: The files called a separate ajax request. sleep(10) is just an example.

Comment: _"run after 10 seconds, I don't know Why"_ = `sleep(10);`  . did you copy someone else's code? make sure you know what a function does before you use it

Comment: The problem is session_start() but What is the reason? I've tested this code with the session_start and without session_start.

Comment: did you mean to say,these are two separate PHP files and when you run both files simultaneously,second file waits until first one gets executed?

Comment: yes. both php files call by ajax request at the same time. <script>runFirstFile(); runSecondFile();</script>

Comment: the reason why the second file run around 10 seconds is because you have `sleep` function executed in your first file. `sleep` will delay the program execution time and not just your first file

Comment: No. The problem is not this case because AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: I found the solution: session_write_close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: [session_write_close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905989/4401901)(); and PHP [Session Lockes](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/)

```
<?php
        // First File
        if(session_id() == '')
            session_start();
        session_write_close();
        sleep(10);
```