# Improve Page performance, Reduce Session loading time and other utilities

Tags: php, performance, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp framework for my application development and included the session component for session management in AppController

```
var $components = array('Session');
```

On each and every page reload `CakeSession::_startSession` is calling which takes merely 7.5 secs (don't know why), and also `FileEngine::read()` which takes 8.5 secs

[image]

**Session statistics**

[image]
**Note**: these standards are given by performance tool

How can i improve my page performance as the session taking too much time

Please help me to get resolve this issue

I'm using cakephp version 2.30

Thanks in advance

**Update**

we got the below link when I've googled about the issue

[session_start seems to be very slow (but only sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385582/session-start-seems-to-be-very-slow-but-only-sometimes)

in answer it has the below function to call

```
session_write_close();   // close write capability
```

And the same we have in CakePhp 2.6 version (in `CakeSession::_startSession()`) where it's not in cake 2.3.0 (which I'm using currently)

So while comparing 2.3.0 & 2.6.0 versions, i found below code which isn't in version 2.3.0,
Can i include this piece of code to resolve the Issue ?

```
self::init();
session_write_close();
self::_configureSession();
```

Please suggest me

Comment: So `833` means `8.33` seconds? Are you sure about that? Wouldn't `7,290` then mean `72.9` seconds? And your page calls really take more than 15 seconds? That sounds like you have some serious server issues, which you should debug further before asking a question here on SO, as it's rather unspecific and open-ended, all people can do is shooting in the dark.

Comment: Here the statistics are in **ms** i.e. 7,290ms @ndm

Comment: Just as explanation: using session_write_close() and starting the session_start($session_id_of_previous_session) again is used to "reset" the session timout to the new value. Else clients are not notified about the new, extended session timeout. Else Clients and Server only keep the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that the problem is the creating of the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) itself - which is file based (writes to the file system). I solved this by using redis as session store ([see this turtorial](http://bloke.org/php/cakephp-redis/)).