# Webapp runs very slowly sometimes

Tags: php, performance, pagespeed

Using PHP, I've developed an ERP system. But sometimes, the customer claims about the speed. Recently, I had the same problem when working in the system and it took a minute for the page to be fully loaded:

[image: Receive Data]

The data was received at 45 seconds... Anyone ideas why this could take so long sometimes? This happens on random pages and handlings at random times. Could this be a problem from the server or from the Internet?

Comment: First check which file is getting the problem. To see this image is not enough information

Comment: *Possible* duplicate of [session_start seems to be very slow (but only sometimes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385582/session-start-seems-to-be-very-slow-but-only-sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a performance issue with the server, it could be a performance issue with the client's internet connection, or it could be a performance issue with the way you have coded soemthing, e.g. a MySQL query.

If your server is shared hosting, then a performance issue with the server may be the most likely explanation.